# What are some good tutorials/books to get me started to QT programing?

Tags: qt4

I'd like to develop a Linux(here mainly KDE)/Win/Mac application using QT. The thing is this would be my first contact with QT framework, so can you please recommend some good tutorials/books for a newibie to get started with QT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "C++ GUI Programming with Qt4" by Jasmin Blanchette is a good start, the first edition is freely available [here](http://www.qtrac.eu/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.zip).

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html) that is part of the QT docs is pretty good, especially if you have never used QT before.

Comment: And the new Qt 4.6 tutorial: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

This book has some of the better reviews: [Foundations of Qt Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598318)

Answer (score 0):

The standard introduction is

> Programming with Qt
>
> Matthias Kalle Dalheimer
>
> O'Reilly Media